# No Such file or directory : hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I deployed Kubernetes on a single node using minikube and then installed hadoop and hdfs with helm. It's working well.
The problem is when i try to copy a file from local to hdfs `$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /data/titles.csv  /data` i get this: No such file or directory

[image: command of hdfs]

this is the path on local :

[image: path of titles.csv]

Comment: not sure where you are running hadoop command and where is your file is store however i think your file is in host machine while hadoop command you are running inside of POD, i would suggest putting file first to inside POD using `kubectl cp` or use the hostpath

Comment: @HarshManvar yesi'm running hadoop inside of pod

Comment: You need to mount your local file system to pod thn you will be directly accessing those file inside pod or else use kubectl cp command to put file from local system to inside of pod direct at data directory

Comment: @HarshManvar i did `kubectl cp "/data/titles.csv" hdfs-namenode-0:titles.csv ` and this appear : default container namenode out of : namenode, namenode exporter, chown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've shown a screenshot of your host's filesystem GUI details panel.

Unless you mount /data folder inside the k8s pod, there will be no /data folder you can put from.

In other words, you should get a similar error with just `ls /data`, and this isn't an HDFS problem since "local" means different things in different contexts.

You have at least 3 different "local" filesystems - your host, the namenode pod, the datanode pod, and possibly also the minikube driver (if using a VM)